# How can I make my other computer run a program?

Tags: windows-7, automation, script

If I have two computers, both running Windows 7, on my home network, is there some way to write a script so that I can click on a single icon on the one computer and make the other computer execute a program?

Clearly, I could do this by accessing the other computer through remote desktop connection and then executing the program, but I would like to avoid (or at least automate) making the connection so I can just click a single icon to have it happen.

Comment: Are you going to make me ask it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Ask what? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(assuming Windows)

You could write a batch file that calls [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553), or create a shortcut to PsExec with the appropriate command line arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified Windows 7.  One does dual boot with Ubuntu, but that isn't relevent here.  I'll give PsExec a try.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman: You need permissions set on the other computers use PsExec, or at least have their login detalis.